# Angular 6 handling of 403 response with new RxJS

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have an interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {
  }


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    const authHeaders = auth.getAuthHeader();
    const authReq = request.clone({headers: authHeaders});

     return next.handle(authReq).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
       if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

       }
     }, (err: any) => {
       if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
         if (err.status === 403) {
           this.router.navigate(['login']);
         }
       }
     });
  }
}
```

it was wornking in Angular 5, but now i've migrated to 6 and this doesn't work anymore.

**It says property 'do' doesn't exist on type Observable.**

Also i've tried to implement the solution from this thread: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017245/how-to-handle-unauthorized-requestsstatus-with-401-or-403-with-new-httpclient?rq=1)
Didn't work as well.

This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209119/property-do-does-not-exist-on-type-observableiproduct) says it is consequence of rxjs changes. After making suggested changes the problem remains (now with 'tap' instead 'do')

here is import section:

```
// import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Note: commented line has been tried as well.

Comment: `Does not work` is a bit vague... Does it go through your error handler? In the 1st `if`?  In the 2nd one?

Comment: @David, added more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<IProduct\[\]>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209119/property-do-does-not-exist-on-type-observableiproduct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

1. run 'npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save';
2. imports should look like this:

> ```
> import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
>
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
> ```

3. in my case there was **NO NEED** to change 'do' -> 'tap';
4. if angular material is used, reinstall might be necessary after running the first command.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working for my project (Angular 6, RxJS 6) I had to make the following changes:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

And modify the snippet from above to be:

(chaining changed to piping, and changed 'do' to 'tap')

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {
  }


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const auth = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    const authHeaders = auth.getAuthHeader();
    const authReq = request.clone({headers: authHeaders});

     return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
       tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
         if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

         }
       }, (err: any) => {
         if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
           if (err.status === 403) {
             this.router.navigate(['login']);
           }
         }
       })
   );
  }
}
```

The reason for this are some [recent changes in RxJS 6](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/).

> Use piping instead of chaining as new operator syntax. The result of one operator is piped into another operator.

And

> Note Some operators have a name change due to name collisions with JavaScript reserved words! These include: do -> tap, catch -> catchError, switch -> switchAll, finally -> finalize.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is `property 'do' doesn't exist on type Observable`, try importing the operator. Put this on top of your file:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

Comment: @UnknwnArtist check your `package.json` file, and please tell us which version of `rxjs` you use? Version 5 doesn't work with Angular 6, hence you'll have to update your `rxjs` to the latest version. Try `import { do } from rxjs/operators`, and let me know if it works. You can also use [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) reference

Comment: @mutantkeyboard,     "rxjs": "^6.0.0", "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0". These are from package.json. Import of "do" doesn't help.

Comment: Ah yes, `do` has been changed to `tap`, since `do` is reserved keyword in JS. [Refer here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)

Comment: @mutantkeyboard i've change "do" to "tap" now it says that property "tap" doesn't exist on Observable :)

Comment: Could you provide us a piece of code with RXSJ related imports?

Comment: @mutantkeyboard `// import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import { tap, of } from 'rxjs/operators';` commented section has been tried as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172517/discussion-between-mutantkeyboard-and-unknwn-artist).

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue, here is how I have resolved

1. ng update (To update all packages and make it compatible with angular 6)
2. npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save (Install a updated version of rxjs)
3. replace following functions throughout the code because they are updated in rxjs

   do => tap,
    catch => catchError,
    switch => switchAll,
    finally => finalize

for more information check the rxjs change-log.

Comment: Did the steps, and still i have property 'tap' doesn't exist on Observable. And another observation - whenever i execute "npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save" angular material modules need to be reinstalled.

Comment: Make sure you are importing it right
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';